# Matlab - Concatenate char array

Tags: arrays, matlab, concatenation

My current code looks like:

```
 result = Month([tokens '*' names])
```

Where the result will be Month filtered on token variable, wildcard, then names where the wildcard is a date.

Now, the date needs to be more specific, this is stored in a char array `dateno` (there are 4 dates in here). e.g:

```
dateno
ans =
20140625
20140618
20140611
20140604
```

I now want result to equal month filtered as before, but using only the dates in dateno. At a glance it seems like I could do

```
result = Month([tokens dateno names])
```

But this gives

```
Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the variable types of `tokens` and `names`? Are those arrays?

Comment: They are of class char, e.g. token = abcd, names=foobar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
result = month(strcat(token,cellstr(dateno),names))
```

which would be a cell array output. If you were looking to get the result in char type, wrap it with `char`.